# 2D Array images swapping

Tags: language-agnostic, dynamic-arrays

i have a problem of how to swap images isnide my 3 * 3 array, for example:

---

mImage image1 image2

image3 image4 image5

image6 image7 image8

---

mImage is the one i would like to swap with the rest, I can swap it only with the next one or with the one below(Sort of like a puzzler).

So the mImage can be swap only with image1 and image3.

What i thought is to swap with i+1 or with i+3 when the mouse is clicked.

Is that a good technique or is there a better approach to this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an image is clicked, check if it's next to `mImage` (i.e. either it's X coordinate is the same as mImage.X and the difference in Y coordinates is equal to 1, or the other way round). If it's true, then you can swap.